# Need advice on this logic...can't find a better title

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm coding [this](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GFCKA/) plugin that validates if a series of checkbox groups have at least `x` options checked.
Each checkbox group is named with the `name` attribute like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]"> // Where `[]` identifies it as a group
```

And the plugin is called like so:

```
/* Grab all checkboxes and make sure 
at least 2 are checked in every group */
$(':checkbox').checkpass(2);
```

If you try the plugin at **http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GFCKA/** you'll see that every time you try to validate, an alert will come up with the number of options left per group you need to check. When all conditions are met the message will not trigger anymore. You'll get the "Passed!" alert.

The plugin works fine if the value passed is greater than one but the problem comes when I pass a value of zero:

```
$(':checkbox').checkpass(0)
```

If the minimum is set to zero it still grabs the default value of `min = 1` so it acts as if the value passed were `1`. Why is this happening? Here's the actual plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.checkpass = function(min) {
        var $ckboxes = this,
            names = [],
            num = 0,
            err = '';
        $ckboxes.each(function() {
            var name = this.name;
            if (!~$.inArray(name, names)) {
                names.push(name);
            }
        });
        min = min || 1;
        for (var i = 0, l = names.length; i < l; i++) {
            $checked = $ckboxes.filter('[name="' + names[i] + '"]:checked');
            if ($checked[min - 1]) {
                num++;
            } else {
                var _remaining = min - $checked.length,
                    _name = names[i].match(/\w+/).toString()
                            .replace(/^\w/, function($0) {
                                return $0.toUpperCase();
                            });
                err += _name + ': Check ' + _remaining + ' more\r\n';
            }
        }
        return {
            isValid: num === names.length,
            errors: err
        };
    };
})(jQuery);


// Test
$('button').click(function() {
    var checkpass = $(':checkbox').checkpass(3);
    if (checkpass.isValid) {
        alert('Passed!');
    } else {
        alert(checkpass.errors);
    };
});​
```

Comment: I don't know the ansawer to you're question but what is this statement if (!~$.inArray(name, names)) { looks intersting !~ never seen it used before

Comment: **@KDM** Is the same as `if ($.inArray(name, names) !== -1)`

Comment: You should update you're code once its complete it looks good for group checkbox validation. looks like could be a good plugin.

Comment: I'll finish this thing later. But I'll post a link here when it's done.

Comment: **@KDM** Here's the plugin http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GFCKA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this logic:

```
min = min || 1;
```

In JavaScript 0 evaluates to false. So the above statement is always setting min to 1 when it is passed in as 0.

You could change it to:

```
min = (typeof min == 'undefined') ? 1 : min;
```

Comment: Oh, man, you're right, missed that! Back to the basics... The problem now is that I still get the menu and whenever I check one option the numbers become negative. I'll have to put another `if` somewhere. I'm so tired I just see blobs instead of characters.